# Reading a first order logic definition, with for all

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I'm trying to read the following FOL for a functional binary relation:

$R \subset X \times Y$

$\forall x \in X, \forall y \in Y, \forall z \in Y, (x,y) \in R \land (x,z) \in  R \implies y = z$

I'm confused on how to read this.  It's my understanding  "∀ __ is True if the value of __ is True for all values of x" and that "∀ __ is False if the value of __ is False for any value of x.

So above, $\forall z \in Y$ will bind $z$ to values where $y \ne z$ and the entire statement will be false.  Am I reading this wrong?

Comment: If you need to read in english, the formula says "For every $x\in X$ and for every $y,z\in Y$, if $(x,y)$ and $(x,z)$ are elements of $R$ then $y=z$". Is a formula of the form $P\rightarrow Q$.

Comment: I don't think it's reading that is the issue, I see that the formula evaluates to false for $y \ne z$ and that is confusing me.  It seems unless $z$ is limited this formula will evaluate to false.

Comment: The form is "For all $x,y,z$ in appropriate sets, (if blah blah about $x,y,z$ then $y=z$)". The false evaluation happens if there exist some $x,y,z$ in appropriate sets for which $R(x,y)$ and $R(x,z)$ and $y<>z$. The variables are bound and so the formula is NOT about $x,y,$ or $z$ -- it's about the binary relation $R$. In English it says "for any $x$ in $X$, there is at most one $y$ in $Y$ for which $R(x,y)$".

Comment: @Ned yes but if variables are bound and $y \ne z$ doesn't that result in false for $\forall z \in Y$, which would cause the entire formula to be false?

Comment: It might help to understand what's going on.  The sentence says that $R$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$, not just a relation within $X \times Y$.

Comment: @RobertShore I think its the defn of the universal quantifier thats confusing me.  For instance it might quantify $(x,y) \lnot \in R$, which should cause the statement to be false and if a statement bound by the universal quantifier is false, doesn't that mean the quantification operation is false?

Comment: @Nick No unless $R(x,y)$ and $R(x,z)$ hold -- the implication is only false if the antecedent is true and the conclusion is false. For example do you see why this sentence is true in the real numbers: "For all $x$, if $x<4$ then $x<7$" ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's worth looking at the innermost part first and understanding what it means:

$(x,y) \in R \land (x,z) \in  R \implies y = z$

Remember, $P \implies Q$ is a logical statement that is true if either:

a) $P$ is false; or
b) $P$ and $Q$ are both true

i.e. if you know that the left-hand side is true, you can conclude that the right-hand side is also true; but if the left-hand side is false you have no information about the right-hand side.

So in this case, $(x,y) \in R \land (x,z) \in  R \implies y = z$ means "If we know that $xRy$ and $xRz$ both hold, then in fact we also know that $y$ and $z$ are equal. However, if either $xRy$ or $xRz$ doesn't hold, then who knows?"

Comment: What I'm getting confused about is the definition of the universal quantifier, in which every value the variable binds to, the statement must be true for the quantifier to be true over all $x$.  I see that $(x,y) \in R$ will be false for some $R$ that is functional with this definition for the quanitifier.  That is my confusion

Comment: @Nick: The statement that needs to be true is not $(x,y)\in R$, but the entire implication $[[(x,y) \in R \land (x,z) \in  R] \implies y = z]$. Perhaps you are getting confused by the lack of brackets in the original version.

Comment: @EricWofsey that brings sense to this!

Comment: @EricWofsey should I have known something about precedence to catch the bracketing issue?

Comment: @Nick: Nah, the original statement is just sloppily written.

Comment: It's a little bit lazy, but the trick to spotting it is that outside of the quantifiers, $x$, $y$ and $z$ have no meaning - so the predicate that the quantifier attaches to *must* be the whole statement, in order to include the variables that are present.

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the bracketing here:
$\forall x \in X, \forall y \in Y, \forall z \in Y, (x,y) \in R \land (x,z) \in  R \implies y = z$

Should be:
$\forall x \in X, \forall y \in Y, \forall z \in Y, ((x,y) \in R \land (x,z) \in  R) \implies y = z$